# Adding map to Range in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to extend `Range` with a `map` function similar to the one on `Array`:

```
extension Range {
    func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Element) -> T) -> [T] {
        var result = Array<T>()
        for i in self {
            result.append(transform(i))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

`Element` is defined by `Range`:

```
struct Range<Element : ForwardIndexType> : …
```

---

I thought this looked fairly good, however when using it I get a compiler error:

```
let cellSubtitles: [String?] = {  // <-- Unable to infer closure type in the current context
    return 0...42.map {
        let week: Int = $0/7
        switch week {
        case 0:  return nil
        case 1:  return "Last Week"
        default: return "\(week) Weeks Ago"
        }
    }
}()
```

Note that the error is for the surrounding closure, not for the one passed to `map`.

Also, Changing the second line above to

```
return (0...42 as Range<Int>).map {
```

gets rid of the error.

I do not understand this as my `map` function should return `[String?]` in both cases. And anyways, I would have assumed that `0...42` is `Range<Int>` also without the cast.

I'm using Swift 2.0.

Comment: `42.map` has precedence over `0...42`. You have to enclose your range in brackets `(0...42).map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Swift 2.0 then `map` is already defined for `Range` since `Range` conforms to `CollectionType`, which implements `map`, so there is no need to define it yourself.

Comment: I have since noticed that. what tripped me up was what Kametrixom mentioned: I missed surrounding my range with brackets.